# Entity Framework Connection String

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Estou criando um projeto utilizando Entity Framework.

Minha dúvida, seria, como posso criar uma connectionString (para SQL Server por exemplo) e definir no meu DBContext de onde ele vai pegar do arquivo Web.config?

DBContext

```
namespace Data
{
    public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBContext() : base("dbName")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Usuarios> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vendedores> Produtos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Por padrão você já deve ter a <connectionStrings> no seu web.config pro `MSSQLLocalDB`. Oque mais vc precisa?

Comment: Eu não tenho a string, eu queria saber como criar ela e como apontar no meu DBContext!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua connectionStrings deve ficar assim no web.config:

**Para criar no LocalDB:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Nome_Arquivo.mdf;Initial Catalog=Nome_Arquivo;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Para criar no SQL Server (caso tenha ele instalado):**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nome_BD;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

A primeira connectionStrings string é criada automaticamente em seu web.config quando você inicia um projeto MVC com EF. Verifique se ela já não existe antes de cria-la e, se desejar, altere para o segundo exemplo.

Você não precisa apontar no seu DBContext. Se quiser que a base já seja criada (CodeFirst), ative o Migrations no `Package Manager Console` digitando:

> Enable-Migrations

Após isso aparecerá o diretório `Migrations` no seu projeto. Abra o arquivo `Configuration.cs` nesse diretório e ative as opções abaixo:

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

Com essas configurações você pode agora usar o comando abaixo no `Package Manager Console`:

> Update-Database

Esse comando criará seu Banco de dados. O arquivo MDF aparecerá na pasta `App-Data` (se você criou um LocalDB) e se você clicar em `Show all files` poderá abri-lo para ver sua base de dados no `Server-Explore`.

Se criou no SQL Server, basta abrir o Management Studio para ver a base de dados.

Seu DbContext deverá estar assim (já com os 2 DbSet da sua pergunta):

```
public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static DBContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<Usuarios> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Vendedores> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda. E no dbcontext, eu não preciso indicar o nome do banco de dados?

Comment: Editei na resposta, mas acho que já deve estar assim. Não é necessário fazer nenhum outro apontamento. O web.config se encarrega de indicar a conexão.

Comment: Obrigada, para finalizar, o que muda IdentityDbContext em vez de DbContext

Comment: É uma classe que usa os tipos padrões do identity. Talvez você não esteja usando em seu projeto. Se criar um exemplo padrão do VS, ele gera assim automaticamente caso utilize o identity.

Comment: Editei pra ficar como o DBContext da sua pergunta. Não tinha reparado que não estava usando Identity.

Comment: Obrigada. Notei que esse String é para conexão com banco do AppData, e se fosse para um banco local do SQL Server diretamente?

Comment: Coloquei a outra string na resposta também.